# Using Google resources, how do I join together SQL Server resources w/ the GCE they're running on?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to produce a google resource report for my manager that includes all the different databases we're running and any relevant associated resource.

I'm exporting `RESOURCES` using gcloud asset export into BigQuery and querying that table. `ASSET_TYPE` can get me the general db types and `RESOURCE.DATA` keys can be extracted to get the specific dbms. But some, like SQL Server, run on 1 to many GCEs. Those are a different `ASSET_TYPE` and by extracting project and `RESOURCE.PARENT` I can find all GCEs that could *potentially* host the SQL Server database but not specifically which one(s)?

Has anyone else tried this or know if there's a better way to extract key metadata from Google?

Comment: Are you referring to "Google Cloud SQL for SQL Server" or something you have deployed on your own Compute Engine instances? Edit your post with details.

Comment: Actually we have both situations, google cloud sql for sql server (GCP) and sql server on GCE.

Comment: The tool Google Asset Report will know about Google Cloud SQL instances, but not Compute Engine instances that you configured with Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: @JohnHanley, good point.  I guess "serverless" should have been my clue about Cloud SQL instances.

Answer (score 0):

Could you attach labels to your resources, and then use that in Bigquery?

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/labels-intro

Comment: We can and do have various labels on resources in GCP.  I'd rather not rely on that since it's dependent on humans.  I had also opened a ticket w/ google and their response was, "it is not within the scope of CAI to get the inventory of the DB running inside a GCE instance"

Comment: Resources should ideally come from Terraform. And labels also in a dry way from Terraform